# Is it appropriate for female tourists in India to wear ball cap style hats?

Tags: india, cultural-awareness, female-travellers

I will be traveling soon to visit India and I’m wondering if it’s appropriate for female tourists to wear ball cap style hats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of hat to wear for business in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47652/what-kind-of-hat-to-wear-for-business-in-india) Although focused on a business trip, baseball hats are discussed.

Comment: It might also depend on where abouts you are going. Goa might be more liberal, and a Muslim area of an untouristy region less so. Uttar Pradesh has the greatest Muslim population.

Answer (score 3):

**It's fine**, in the sense that nobody will be offended or find it particularly odd, but will it mark you as an obvious tourist.  That said, assuming your profile photo is accurate, you will stand out as non-Indian anyway.

A baseball cap would not be appropriate in more formal settings like offices, weddings, fancy restaurants etc, but that's the same in the US too.

In general, baseball caps are a *very* American thing, wearing one anywhere outside the US is likely to immediately get you tagged as American.